# Ui bootstrap doesn't show after adding object to controller

Tags: angularjs, object, angular-ui-bootstrap

So my ui bootstrap model window is working correctly but when I add an object to the controller it stops showing and it doesn't give me any error in consol.

When my controller looks like this:

```
"use strict";

app.controller('RegisterModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModalInstance', '$http', 'ngAuthSettings', 'registerService',
function($scope, $location, $uibModalInstance, $http, ngAuthSettings, registerService) {

var $ctrl = this;

$ctrl.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
/*
$ctrl.registerInfo = {
    email: $ctrl.registerData.email,
    nick: $ctrl.registerData.nick,
    password: $ctrl.registerData.password,
    password_confirmation: $ctrl.registerData.confirm_password
};
*/

$ctrl.registerSubmit = function(registerInfo) {
    console.log('im in registerSubmit controller function');

    registerService.registerUser(registerInfo);
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$ctrl.showCookiesRules = function() {
    $location.url("/cookiesrules");
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$ctrl.showRules = function() {
    $location.url("/rules");
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
}]);
```

Everything works just fine but when i delete /* just before registerInfo object it stops showing. What is wrong with this object? I want it to create this object to pass it in function and then pass it to function in service.

Comment: I *assume* you are also deleting */ at the end of the comment block?

Comment: Where does `registerData` is defined ?

Comment: Yes Brian i delete */ aswell. registerData is the ng-model of inputs for example: <input type="text" placeholder="powtórz hasło" ng-model="$ctrl.registerData.confirm_password" .... />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you should do is initiate `$ctrl.registerInfo`:

```
$ctrl.registerInfo = {};
```

The data doesn't exist when the controller runs, so you are trying to set the properties of `$ctrl.registerInfo` without non-existent data. Once your form is filled out, the properties/data will be set.

**An alternative option** would not be to initialize at all, and simply set your form model to `registerData.confirm_password`, and when you call `registerSubmit`, call it with `registerSubmit(registerData)`. That will send the data to that method without having to initialize in the controller:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="powtórz hasło"
        ng-model="registerData.confirm_password" />

<!-- abbreviated (other form fields here -->

<input type="submit" ng-click="registerSubmit(registerData)" />
```

If you need the data afterwards, in registerSubmit, add a line:

```
$ctrl.registerInfo = registerInfo;
```

However, I am not sure you'd want to hang onto the password there.

AngularJS Form Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: It still didn't display but i wrap whole thing and put it into function which fire on input[submit] click and now i think it is working perfectly